# Eliminate NAs within each group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have ended up with rows that have NAs that correspond to a column that was deleted and I want to get rid of those NAs. This would turn the example df below from three rows to one row and leave me one set of variables for each group.

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("a", "a", "a"), var1 = c(1, NA, NA), var2 = c(NA, 4, NA), var3 = c(NA, NA, 
2), var4 = c(1, NA, NA), var5 = c(NA, 4, NA), var6 = c(NA, NA, 2), var7 = c(1, NA, NA), 
var8 = c(NA, 4, NA), var3 = c(NA, NA, 2))
```

I know how to get rid of whole rows with NAs or columns with NAs, but am not sure how to collapse this.

Comment: how do you still keep it as a matrix form? You have pivot it right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the example, it can be done with `summarise_all`, assuming that there is only single non-NA element for each column per 'group'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   summarise_all(na.omit)
# A tibble: 1 x 10
#  group  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6  var7  var8 var3.1
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 a         1     4     2     1     4     2     1     4      2
```

Answer (score 1):

One `base R` option could be:

```
aggregate(. ~ group, 
          FUN = function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
          na.action = na.pass, 
          data = df)

  group var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var3.1
1     a    1    4    2    1    4    2    1    4      2
```

It also makes the assumption that there is only a single non-NA value per variable per group.